# How can I transplant my Cygwin installation to another machine/architectureI?

Tags: cygwin

The specific problem I have is this: I have an old (but up-to-date) Cygwin 32-bit installation that has evolved over the past ten years or so. I want to move to a 64-bit Cygwin, with the same facilities.

While the Cygwin graphical installer is moderately nice, it is not "transportable" (Ie you can't copy-and-paste the lines in its windows). So what I'm looking for is this:

1. A way to extract a list of currently-installed packages from Cygwin
2. A command-line method to say to the installer "Please install this list"

Is this possible? I know I could do it by adding packages ad-hoc, as I find I need them, but this usually happens according to Murphy's Law; that is, either when I'm in a hurry, or don't have an Internet connection, or both.

Comment: Please be aware that not all 32-bit packages are available in the 64-bit version ...

Comment: @DavidPostill : Yes, thank you, I knew that but it's good to have it recorded here.

Comment: I can't think of an easy way to do this. You might get a better response from the [cygwin mailing list](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/) where most of the cygwin experts and developers hang out ...

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for the command-line interface to the Cygwin installer: https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.setup.cli

It allows you to give a list of packages on the command line. You can get the list of installed packages from your 32-bit installation using the `cygcheck` utility (see the man page for how to list installed packages).